# Java - Default File Attributes when creating a directory

Tags: java, file, permissions

Our Java application runs in the JBoss application server and writes directories to the underlying Unix file system by using the method File::mkdirs().

We can observe that the file permissions set by this process are different than the ones that are set when creating the directory from the command line as the same user. No explicit permissions are set in the application code.

How does the Java Runtime decide which permissions to assign implicitly to the newly created directory?

Comment: which permissions are set when the dirs are created by the java process? from a simple test I made here, they are the same as the created by user on cli

Comment: That's what I would expect. But they are different in our case. That's why I would like to know how the implicit permission setting is defined in the Java specification.

Comment: ok, but HOW much they are different? show both the permissions set on both case, so we can try to understand better

Comment: CLI: **drwxrwsr-x**
JBoss: **drwxr-sr-x**

Comment: probably is something with your jboss permission, or jboss-user created, from what I searched, but nothing much clear

Comment: Are you executing that command line as the same user as whom JBoss runs?  Different users may create files with different default permissions.

Comment: @VGR: Yes, that's the strange thing. The same user produces different permissions.

Comment: Perhaps your command line shell has a different umask than the umask of the JBoss process?  I don’t know of an easy way to test that using Java, but you can add a line to the JBoss startup script that prints it out.

Comment: In any event, you might have better luck with `Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(filename), PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxr-x")))`.

Comment: @VGR: but the umask should be the same if the user is the same, shouldn't it? I wanted to avoid to fix it via explicit setting of permissions via the application, but if there is no other way to manipulate this behaviour, I will go with PosixFilePermissions.